# Missing Json Data while uploading axios to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

My code in not functioning sometimes.

here is my Upload.jsx

```
    function FileUpload() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
      
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
       
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/form", formData)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Default file input example</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="file"
          onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
        />
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
       </Form.Group>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

and here is my app.js

```
const fileupload = require('express-fileupload')
app.use(express.json({limit:'5000mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit:'5000mb', parameterLimit:50000000 }));

    app.post("/form", (req, res) => {
    fs.writeFile(req.files.file.name, req.files.file.data, (err)=>{
        err && console.log(err);
        !err && console.log('completed');
      })
      })
```

Everything is fine when I am uploading any other files excepts json file. File size doesn't matter. I am able to upload 900mb of file without any issue.

the problem is when I am uploading a json file size of 250mb(or any sized) only, its missing data and saved to the server only 12mb - 35mb(randomly sized).

And sometimes fully uploaded and saved without any missing data.

I don't understand what I am missing

Please help. Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please send the response back to the application from the server and give a try like this

```
const fileupload = require('express-fileupload')
app.use(express.json({limit:'5000mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit:'5000mb', parameterLimit:50000000 }));
app.post("/form", (req, res) => {
  fs.writeFile(req.files.file.name, req.files.file.data, (err)=>{
    if(err){ 
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
      return
    }
    console.log('completed');
    res.status(200).send('ok');        
  })
})
```

Comment: same results. when I logging the browser console, its showing `Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)`  


`xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:5000/form net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`


`polling-xhr.js:198 GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NhrmCU- net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: the console showing error only when I am uploading json file.

Comment: no error on node server. logging 'completed' But each time server is restarting .

Comment: Do you have any solution please? I am still stuck.

Comment: Hey I fixed it. This was issue on nodemon package, I add config file to package.json and it works finally. Thank you for your time.